# Mechanical properties crown cap

Tags: material-science, design

What are the important mechanical properties to look at when designing a crown cork and why?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is crown cork? Can you get a picture and explain more?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE. I'm afraid this is an engineering question and out of place here. You could try asking on the [Engineering Stack Exchange](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @lucas: [this is a crown cork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_cork)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @JohnRennie. If you have any remarks on what has to be looked at from a physics point of view, please share them.

Comment: This is a designing problem and very things must be considered like money, safety, healthy, easy  use, technology of manufacturing, technology of setup, etc.